# Why is Intellij not allowing me to use VBox class?

Tags: java, javafx

In my Intellij IDEA, I am receiving an error that it "Cannot resolve symbol 'VBox'". I have clearly imported VBox with:

```
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox
```

Is there a fix? My current code is below:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class Main extends Application {
    Scene scene1, scene2;
    Stage window;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label1 = new Label("This is scene one!");
        Button button1 = new Button("Go to scene two!");
        button1.setOnAction(event -> window.setScene(scene2));

        Vbox layout1 = new VBox(20);
        layout1.getChildren().addAll(label1, button1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong: `Vbox layout1 = new VBox(20);`

Correct: `VBox layout1 = new VBox(20);`

It's called VBox, not Vbox. Upper/lowercase matters a lot in programming.

Comment: Mistake in my post... I had that, as you can see in the huge code block at the bottom...

Comment: I added a snippet of your code in my answer, you missed it in one place.

Comment: @IPSDSILVA you have it incorrect in the post text and in the code

Comment: Thanks... silly mistake... I missed. I had the error in two places. You caught the one that I missed. Thanks!

Comment: @Nand Will accept in 11 minutes, when I can. SO is giving me an error that I have to wait. Thanks for the help and clarification though!